# Getting the last value of a column for an object with many entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please consider the below *Repair_Table* of a car-repair workshop.

I'm trying to get the **last "Repair_Status" value** for **each car** within a given **day**.

"Repair_Update" column will have a new entry for each change during the car repair process: like the repair status, the repair name or the repair team and repair sub-task which are stored in a different table..

I tried this query but it's not giving me what I need:

```
select distinct(Car_ID), Repair_Status
from Repair_Table r1
left join (select Car_ID, max(Repair_Update) from Repair_Table 
group by Car_ID) r2
on r2.Repair_Update = r1.Repair_Update
where convert(date,Repair_Start) = '20180122'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are an easy way to do this:

```
select rt.*
from (select rt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by car_id, cast(repair_update as date)
                                order by repair_update desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from Repair_Table rt
      where convert(date, Repair_Start) = '20180122'
     ) rt
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can remove the `where` clause if you want this information on multiple dates -- or even on all dates.

Answer (score 1):

Using row_number() function:

```
select Car_ID, Repair_Status
from (
    select Car_ID, Repair_Status
    row_number() over (partition by Car_ID order by Repair_Update desc) as rnk
    from Repair_Table
  ) t
where t.rnk = 1
```